Memory Leak in Apache Spark application
We are currently trying to port our Spark job to Spark 3. Because of this we need to switch from the legacy manager (i.e. spark.memory.useLegacyMode true) to the unified memory manager.
However as soon as we switch awat from the legacy manager (i.e. spark.memory.useLegacyMode false) our spark job fails to complete: it exhausts all the JVM heap and eventually fails with a worker heartbeat error.
The simplified version of our job, which also reproduces the issue is, as follows:
        val eventsRDD: RDD[Event] = ...
        val eventsBySession = eventsRDD
            .keyBy(_.sessionId)
            .filter { case (sessionId, event) =>
                sessionId match {
                case None => {
                    Logger.sessionWarning(s"sessionId is undefined for event $event")
                    false
                }
                case Some(sessionId) if !isSessionIdValid(sessionId) => {
                    Logger.sessionWarning(s"sessionId is invalid for event $event")
                    false
                }
                case _ => true
                }
            }

        val sessions = eventsBySession
            .repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(new HashPartitioner(120))
            .mapPartitions { (allEventsForSession: Iterator[(Option[String], Event)]) =>
                // IteratorUtil.groupByKey is optimization of Spark's groupByKey transformation
                IteratorUtil.groupByKey(allEventsForSession).map { case (key, lines) =>
                    val events: Seq[JsonNode] = lines.toSeq
                    ....
                }
            }


The definition of the Event class:
case class Event(str: String) {
  @transient lazy val json = str.parseJson
}

The number of events that need to be processed is large (over 400M). The size of each event is 170kB (the average size of str variable is 60kB and the average size of json is 110kB).
We noticed that the memory leak is caused by lazy-triggering the JSON deserialization: if we change  the definition of the Event class to the one below, the job finishes successfully also with the unified memory manager:
case class Event(str: String) {
  def json: JsonNode = str.parseJson
}


I have two questions:

Is lazy-loading of variables something that is discouraged in Spark jobs?
Do you have an explanation why lazy-loading of variables fills-up JVM heap when using the new Spark's unified memory manager but works perfectly fine when using the legacy memory manager?

